# How to pass styles via props with styled components without having to create the component inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I cannot find another way to give my props dynamic styles without creating the `styled-component` inside the `Text` component. For performance I'd like to create the component outside of the `Text` component.

### Styled Component

```
import React, { ReactChildren } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


export const Text = ({ as = 'p', children, styles = {} }) => {
  const newStyles = Object.entries(styles).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    return `${acc}${key}: ${value};`
  }, '')
  const Component = styled.p`
    ${newStyles}
    color: #000;
  `
  return <Component as={as}>{children}</Component>
}
```

### Desired Usage

```
<Text styles={{ height: "10px" }} />
```

### Output HTML

```
<p styles="height: 10px" />
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just do the `Object.entries` bit outside the styled-component and pass it in?

Comment: Ye, but the issue is having the `Component` inside the `Text` component. So if I were to take both out I wouldn't be able to return a component from a function. But maybe I can and I just cannot see it :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above code is confusing in that you want to apply styles to the DOM `style` property, but you're also applying them as CSS styles to a classname. There's no need to create this composed component because styled-components already handles `as`, `children`, and `style` properties without composing:

[image: Edit Styled Components - "Styles" Typescript]

Example 1:

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { Interpolation } from "styled-components";

export type TextProps = {
  as?: string | React.ComponentType<any>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  styles?: Interpolation<React.CSSProperties>;
};

const Component = styled.p<TextProps>`
  ${({ styles }) => styles}
  color: #000;
`;

export const Text = ({
  as,
  children,
  styles
}: TextProps): React.ReactElement => (
  <Component styles={styles} as={as}>
    {children}
  </Component>
);

export default Text;
```

Example 2:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Text = styled.p`
  color: #000;
`;

export default Text;
```

Example 3:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export type TextComponentProps = {
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  styles?: React.CSSProperties;
};

const TextComponent = ({
  children,
  className,
  styles
}: TextComponentProps): React.ReactElement => (
  <p className={className} style={styles}>
    {children}
  </p>
);

const Text = styled(TextComponent)`
  color: #000;
`;

export default Text;
```

Usage:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "./Box";
import Text from "./Text";
import Text2 from "./Text2";
import Text3 from "./Text3";
import "./styles.css";

const App = (): React.ReactElement => (
  <div className="app">
    <h1>Example 1 - "styles" as CSS Styles</h1>
    <Box>
      <Text styles={{ height: "10px" }}>Hello</Text>
      <Text as="h1">Goodbye</Text>
    </Box>
    <hr />
    <h1>Example 2 - "style" as DOM styles</h1>
    <Box>
      <Text2 style={{ height: "10px" }}>Hello</Text2>
      <Text2 as="h1">Goodbye</Text2>
    </Box>
    <hr />
    <h1>Example 3 - "styles" as DOM styles</h1>
    <Box>
      <Text3 styles={{ height: "10px" }}>Hello</Text3>
      <Text3 as="h1">Goodbye</Text3>
    </Box>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Output:
[image]

On that note, it sounds like you might be trying to do something I did with [composabled-styled-components](https://composable.mattcarlotta.sh/), although I wouldn't recommend it because it [doesn't work with SSR apps](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3238).

Comment: Thanks Matt... Interestingly this is not valid TS, which of course I didn't mention in the original question.

Comment: Updated answer to include typescript examples + typescript codesandbox.

Comment: On a related note, if you want to interpolate `props` within the `styles` property that adds CSS styles to a classname, then use the [css](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) helper function (you can interpolate an object or a template literal).

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!! i used this solution with storybook and works perfectly...how can i use this but in react-native? i'm using storybook and can`t make it work, any idea?

Comment: Oddly enough it seems `Interpolation` is no longer exported from styled-components. I get this error: “Module 'styled-components' has no exported member 'Interpolation'. Did you mean to use 'import Interpolation from styled-components' instead?” My import line: `import styled, { css, Interpolation } from 'styled-components';`

Comment: @BrandonDurham Although this example is quite old, it appears that `Interpolation` is a valid [exported type](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/types.ts#L83-L95). I'm not sure if you're using `@types/styled-components`, but that may be causing the type error (the package is either still required or no longer required since they moved to v6).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `ref` on the styled component in order to set the style in an effect like this:

```js
const Component = styled.p`
  background-color: red;
`;

const Text = ({ as = 'p', children, styles = {} }) => {
  const newStyles = Object.entries(styles).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    return `${acc}${key}: ${value};`
  }, '')
  
  const ref = React.createRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style = newStyles;
  }, []);
  
  return <Component ref={ref} as={as}>{children}</Component>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Text styles={{ height: "10px" }}>This paragraph is 10px high</Text>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@17/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. It feels odd to me that I would need to use the rendered DOM rather than using react for this. I will consider this, thank you